# FaceTime Calls from Contacts Only?

Tags: ios, macos, facetime

Is there a way to only allow facetime calls from people in your address book?

Comment: Good question. One thing to keep in mind is that you can also block specific callers. If someone is on you a lot (against your wish), you can go to Recents, select the (i) on the right, then scroll to the bottom to "Block this Caller". I am of the opinion that someone will lose steam rather quickly if they have to sign up for a new email address or phone number every time they want to bother you.

Answer (score 4):

### Not really.

On OS X, I wasn't able to find any possibility of doing this. I'm eager to be proven wrong on that point, of course.

---

On iOS, you can kinda do it - by abusing Do Not Disturb. Following these steps will, of course, make it so that your device won't show you notifications. At all.

Really want to do this? Ok, let's get started:

1. Find your Do Not Disturb preferences.

   - **iOS 5/6**: Settings > Notifications > Do Not Disturb
   - **iOS 7**: Settings > Do Not Disturb
2. Manually turn on Do Not Disturb

   - **iOS 5/6**: Root settings window, it's a switch.
   - **iOS 7**: In the Do Not Disturb window, there's a 'Manual' switch. Activate it.
3. Turn off Scheduling:

[image]
4. Select 'Allow calls from', and set it to 'All Contacts':

[image]

Optionally, disable the two-calls-in-three-minutes feature. I wouldn't though - it's kinda important for emergencies.

Now, your iOS device won't accept FaceTime calls from anyone not in your contacts - at the price of not being able to receive notifications, either.